# User role can't be set

Tags: user-roles, user-registration

I don't know, but it seems that the new Wordpress version (6.0.2) overrides the role variable in the `wp_insert_user` function. Before it worked properly, but now the value defined by default in the wordpress dashboard takes precedence over the `wp_insert_user` function. 
Here is the code that worked properly before. Depending on the page where the user was at the time of registration, his role is defined.

```
if (is_page('register')) {
    $user_role = 'customer';
} elseif (is_page('become-agent')) {
    $user_role = 'agent';
}
$user_infos = [
    'user_login'        => $user_login,
    'user_pass'         => $user_pass,
    'user_email'        => $user_email,
    'user_registered'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'role'            => $user_role
];
$new_user_id = wp_insert_user($user_infos);
```

But unfortunately there is only the default predefined role in the wordpress dashboard that is assigned. I need the role assigned to the registration. 
But despite this, I tried to modify the role of the user just after registration with wp_insert_user, and the action hooks `user_register`, `add_user_role` and `set_user_role`; None of them works

Comment: `customer` and `agent` aren't roles in stock WordPress, so they'll be provided by a theme or a plugin. Have your changed themes or deactivated any plugins recently? Are you sure all the plugins in use are functioning correctly in 6.0.2?

Comment: Agree with @PatJ - if you have WooCommerce (WC) running WC adds a "customer" role.

Comment: This is a plugin that I made myself, the theme also, the custom roles are regitered. So they appear in the wordpress dashboard. I even set the default role to customer. And you can guess the result, even though I am on the agent page, the new user has customer as role.

Comment: "*just after registration*" - I see `is_page()` in your code, so what was the original hook you used that worked before? And do you remember on what page did you notice the issue for the 1st time? Have you tried checking for the role, e.g. `if ( get_role( $user_role ) ) { // insert user } else { echo "role $user_role does not exist"; }` ?

Comment: @SallyCJ I tried your suggestion to verify if role exists. Indeed, it says it doesn't exist. `$user_role` is undefinied. I am using the init action hook to add the users. Maybe `is_page` isn't a function that can be called at this stage. Here's some additive infos: I created a registration form which I attached to a shortcode. This shortcode, I placed it in both pages.

Comment: Yes, `init` is too early, so conditional tags like `is_page()` should not be called there - try a later hook like `wp` or `template_redirect`. And if `$user_role` was undefined, then that's because 1) you didn't define it outside of your if-else block, and 2) you incorrectly called `is_page()` and therefore `$user_role` was never got defined. And now I wondered how come your code worked before..

Comment: That's exactly the question I'm asking myself. And I don't remember changing that code. Thanks for your help.